# How to disable maya user interface when custom window opens?

Tags: python, user-interface, maya

Im building a custom UI in python for maya and I need to know how to disable the rest of the may UI so that my custom UI is the only thing that is useable until it is closed. Much like when you open the file browser in maya and you cant do anything in maya until you're done using the file browser.

Thanks guys!

```py
import maya.cmds as cmds

def namewindow(*args):
         
            
                
    cmds.window('namewindow', title = 'Name Kitbash Item', w = 350, h = 100, s = False)
    
    parentlayout = cmds.rowColumnLayout(adjustableColumn = True)
    cmds.text('Enter name of item to add to kitbash.', h = 30)
    
    
    
    
    global textfield
    textfield = ''
    textfield = cmds.textField()
    
    
    cmds.separator(h = 20)
    cmds.button(l = 'Add to Kitbash')
    
    
    
    
    cmds.showWindow()
namewindow()
```

Comment: Sounds like you’re looking for a `modal` window. If you’re using PySide/Qt this is quite trivial, but I’m not entirely sure how to do it with the built-in Maya UI wrappers. Can you post the code you have so far?

Comment: I just added the relevant code to the post.

Comment: I want to make it so nothing else in the Maya UI can be used while this window is open

Comment: Also as far as I know, I'm not useing pyside (tbh i don't really know what that is). Im kind of a noob

Comment: You may have a look at `cmds.layoutDialog` instead. It creates a modal dialog containing a `formLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

Like `@ababak` mentioned, you can probably use `cmds.layoutDialog` to create a modal dialog using Maya's built-in Qt wrappers.

However, if you just want to go straight to Qt instead, which I highly recommend, here's some simple scaffolding to get you started:

```py
import shiboken2
import maya.OpenMayaUI as MayaUI
import maya.cmds as cmds
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets



class testModalDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    '''Simple QDialog example
    
    Args:
        modal (bool, optional): Show a modal window?
        autoShow (bool, optional): Auto-show window after creating class instance?
        initialSize (tuple (int), optional): Initial dialog size given as (width, height)
        parent (QWidget|mixed, optional): Dialog parent. If None, Maya's main window will be used
    '''
    
    def __init__(self, modal=True, autoShow=True, initialSize=(600, 300), parent=None):
        self.mayaMainWindow = shiboken2.wrapInstance(long(MayaUI.MQtUtil.mainWindow()), QtWidgets.QWidget)
        super(testModalDialog, self).__init__(parent or self.mayaMainWindow)
        self.setWindowTitle('This is a {} dialog'.format('modal' if modal else 'standard'))
        self.resize(initialSize[0], initialSize[1])
        
        # Build UI
        self.setupUi()
        
        # Setup connections
        self.setupConnections()
        
        # Show dialog if requested
        if autoShow and modal:
            print('Showing you a modal dialog')
            self.exec_()
        elif autoShow:
            print('Showing you a standard dialog')
            self.show()
        else:
            print('Dialog class is built, but we\'re not automatically showing a dialog. You must manually call the relevant method to display the UI')

    def setupUi(self):
        '''Populates the UI elements'''

        # Main dialog layout
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(3, 3, 3, 3)
        self.layout.setSpacing(0)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        
        # Label
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel("Hello, I am a label")
        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        
        # Spacer
        self.layout.addItem(
            QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(0, 30, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        )
        
        # Button
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('I am a button that stretches to full with')
        self.layout.addWidget(self.button1)
        
        # Spacer
        self.layout.addItem(
            QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(0, 30, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        )
        
        # Button
        self.button2Layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.button2Layout.addItem(
            QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(0, 0, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        )
        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('And I am a button that only take up as much space as I need')
        self.button2Layout.addWidget(self.button2)
        self.button2Layout.addItem(
            QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(0, 0, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        )
        self.layout.addLayout(self.button2Layout)
        
        
        # Spacer to absorb remaining vertical space
        # You actually probably don't want this here, just using it as an example to show expanding spacers
        self.layout.addItem(
            QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(0, 0, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        )
        
    def setupConnections(self):
        '''Setup all connections like callbacks for button clicks, etc'''
        
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.button1click)
        self.button2.clicked.connect(self.button2click)
        
    def button1click(self, *args):
        '''Button 1 has been clicked (callback)'''
        
        self.displayAlert('Button 1', 'You clicked the first button')
        
    def button2click(self, *args):
        '''Button 2 has been clicked (callback)'''
        
        self.displayAlert('Button 2', 'You clicked the second button')
        
    def displayAlert(self, title, message):
        '''Simple wrapper for cmds.confirmDialog'''
        
        cmds.confirmDialog(message=message, icon='information', title=title, button=["OK"])
        
        
print('Running modal')
tester = testModalDialog()
print('Back in main thread. Dialog instance is: {}'.format(tester))
```

Qt docs might come in handy: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/reference-overview.html